# Visual Studio VSPackage icon displays different colors

Tags: visual-studio-2017, png, visual-studio-extensions, imaging, vspackage

I am trying to provide an icon for the button that activates my custom VSPackage extension.

When designing the icon, the following colors are used:

Foreground: #fff (white)
Background: #a375e7 (light purple)

When displaying the icon in the button within Visual Studio (Solution Explorer, top), the following colors are seen:

Foreground: #000 (black)
Background: #5c1fb7 (dark purple)

The icon is **not** disabled.

The icon comes from a PNG file with multiple icons in it. Each icon is 16 x 16 pixels.

Admittedly, I am not an expert on image manipulation so my educated guess is it's something simple concerning image settings at design time, prior to export.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a dark theme in VS?

Comment: That is correct, @SergeyVlasov.

Comment: Try to test with a light theme.

Comment: OK. I will give it a shot when I am in the office tomorrow morning. I still need to get it to display properly in the dark theme though... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to make icons appear with the correct contrast ratio in the Visual Studio dark theme, an inversion is applied programmatically.

See [Color inversion for dark themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio#color-inversion-for-dark-themes) in **Images and Icons for Visual Studio** documentation.

To opt-out from the inversion, you can try to set top-right pixel to cyan (#00FFFF). From [IVsImageService2.ThemeDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsimageservice2.themedibits?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsImageService2_ThemeDIBits_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_UInt32_) documentation:

> Applies theming to BGRA32 device-independent bitmap bits. The luminosity of the image is transformed so that the constant "halo" luminosity blends in with the background. This has the effect of eliminating the halo visually. The "halo" luminosity is an immutable constant, and is not calculated from the input image. Images which contain cyan (#00FFFF) in their top-right pixel are not inverted. Instead, the top-right pixel is cleared (RGBA are all set to 0) and S_OK is returned without otherwise modifying the image.

Comment: This worked. I spent a good deal of time on that very same page yesterday looking for the answer. I got lazy at the end and stopped reading, right before the line about inversion, LOL. Thank you. @Sergey!